# Running a code behind routine from an <a href

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a link that looks like a button from this html

```
<p class="link-styleContact"><a href="#"><span>Email Contact Form</span></a></p>
```

can I run a code behind file when this is clicked on by adding the routine name to the href? like below

```
<p class="link-styleContact"><a href="ContactFormClicked" 
    runat="server"><span>Email Contact Form</span></a></p>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control instead and subscribe to the `Click` event.

It will appear as a link on the browser and you can have your code in the event handler.

aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="myLink" Text="Hi" OnClick="LinkButton_Click" runat="server"/>
```

Code behind (VB.NET):

```
Sub LinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
   ' Your code here
End Sub
```

Code behind (C#):

```
void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // your code here
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`HtmlAnchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.aspx) control and set the `ServerClick` event handler. This is basically the `a` element with a `runat="server"` attribute:

aspx:

```
<a id="AnchorButton" onserverclick="HtmlAnchor_Click" runat="server">
     Click Here
</a>
```

Code behind (VB.NET):

```
Sub HtmlAnchor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   ' your code here
End Sub
```

Code behind (C#):

```
  void HtmlAnchor_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // your code here
  }
```

Comment: c#...pah...vb's `handles` clause is even more better-er... :-)

Comment: two ?'s 1. CAN i reference code to run from an href tag and 2. using the link button loses my graphics on the page which are set by the <a tags, can i use the asp:linkbutton within the span tags?

Comment: @user959663 - I have updated my answer. As for your question 1 - I hope my update answers it. As for question 2, yes, this should work fine in regards to the span tag. I don't know what you mean by losing your graphics - there is nothing in the question that explains that.

Comment: @kurukurupa - If you use the aspx markup to wireup the handler, your don't need a `handles` clause in vb.net. As for "better-er" - that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: I know the basics.  Was more hinting at VB, since OP tagged vb.net (not c# as in your original answer).  VS has a nice feature where you double-click the control, and the code-behind opens up using the handles clause by default...  Anyway, not like it's a big deal either way -- as you say, opinion...

Comment: LinkButton does a postback which I am trying to prevent :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979847/how-to-prevent-postback-on-asp-button-while-displaying-a-popup-using-jquery

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - then don't use a server side control?

Comment: If you can please take a look at this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001579/why-is-linkbutton-not-executing-the-click-function-from-code-behind. I am trying to display a modal popup in my Visual Web Part on button click inside a GridView row without doing a Postback.

Comment: Does Sub HtmlAnchor_Click require a Handles clause to actually handle the click from <a>?

Comment: @MichaelPotter - the name doesn't matter. It just needs to match the name on the `onserverclick` attribute of the server side control.

Comment: Here is what I am trying that I can not make work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46148113/

Comment: The problem there is that you are pasting it on the client side. These tags should be processed in the server side (what they output to the page is completely different from what's in your editor). It has been a long time since I've done any web forms - I don't think I can help further, @MichaelPotter

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control and handle the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.click.aspx) event.

Comment: It does a postback which I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the `<a>` tag specifically, then some options:

You can use `<a href="http://example.com" onclick="return foo()">`, where `foo()` is a javascript function.

You can also use the page's onload event to handle it, like this:

`<a href="http://example.com?e=foo">`, and then in the pageload() event, do this: `...if request.querystring("e") = "foo" then...`

But otherwise, as others have suggested, the `<asp:linkbutton>` control is a good choice.

Comment: LinkButton does a postback which I am trying to avoid.