# How to prevent postback on asp button while displaying a popup using JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following `ItemTemplate` in my GridView:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" ID="btnShow" CssClass="btnSearch" Text="View All" CommandName="ViewAll" OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;" OnCommand="btnShow_Command" CommandArgument='<%#((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

For the `ItemTemplate` I have a button which opens a popup window when clicked by using the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btnSearch").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
    });
});

function myfunction() {
}
```

my `Command` code-behind:

```
protected void btnShow_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;

            if (e.CommandName == "ViewAll")
            {
                index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                DataTable cacheTable = HttpContext.Current.Cache["ResultsTable"] as DataTable;

                string column = cacheTable.Rows[index].Field<string>("Guideline");
                string test = BookingResults.Rows[index].Cells[7].Text;
                string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(column);

                ResultsDiv.InnerHtml = html;
                //tbGL.Text = html;
                //upData.Update();
                //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I added the `OnClientClick="myfunction(); return false;"` because it was doing a postback each time I clicked. If I have multiple rows, it only works the first time I click but any time after, the popup is not displayed when another or the same button is clicked.

How do I resolve it so no matter which button is clicked the popup is displayed without doing a postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have not showed up the implementation of your method **myfunction()**, in case the **myfunction()** method have any syntactical error then the **OnClientClick** event will be void and it will post-back/submit the form to the server.

Try to remove the call from **OnClientClick** and just implement your logic at jquery **on click event** by using **class selector** as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btnSearch").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).val() + " Clicked"); // you can put your method mymethod() here 
            // you can put youe popup logic here

            return false; 

        });
    });
```

You can also see this example of [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ge534ba5/1/)

Comment: If I have multiple rows, only works the first time and then any time after, the popup window does not show up :/

Comment: Once I hit the OK in the alert, it displays the pop up and reloads the page :/ Maybe because it is an ASP button?

Comment: This is the HTML source I see: `<input type="button" name="ctl00$ctl39$g_0cfd2950_c7c7_494a_9d27_e3ec2cbd2e45$BookingResults$ctl02$btnShow" value="View All" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ctl39$g_0cfd2950_c7c7_494a_9d27_e3ec2cbd2e45$BookingResults$ctl02$btnShow&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="ctl00_ctl39_g_0cfd2950_c7c7_494a_9d27_e3ec2cbd2e45_BookingResults_ctl02_btnShow" class="btnSearch" />` It is still using the `__doPostBack()` function for some reason. Is there anything I can use beside ASP Buttons which doesn't do postback?

Comment: Try Adding **return false;** at the end of the statement of **click** event.

Answer (score 0):

Put it out on the  tag or <%: Html.BeginForm %> tag

Answer (score 0):

```
OnClientClick="return myfunction(); 

function myfunction(){
// you can put youe popup logic here 

    return false;

}
```

Using like this your button never do post back.

Comment: Only works on the first click. Any time after nothing shows up.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this.  Turns out the javascript fired on the first click modified the DOM such that the next time the javascript ran, it was invalid.  That, for some reason, caused the postback to fire.  After I fixed that, the `OnClientClick="myFunction(); return false;"` worked every time.