# Clickable Link Not appearing on page from generated anchor tag

Tags: vb.net

I have some .js code that generates the following anchor tag:

```
<a name="link_274_4" id="link_274" onserverclick="DownloadInspection_Click" runat="server">2017-09-10</a>
```

I cut and paste that out of the DOM Explorer of IE.

That link is not clickable on the page that I am displaying.

Here is the vb.net that I want it to run:

```
Sub DownloadInspection_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim pk As Integer = CInt(button.ID.Replace("link_", ""))

    Dim FileNamePrefix As String = CStr(pk)

    Dim PreApprovalDir = "C:\\Data"

    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(PreApprovalDir)
    Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim fri As FileInfo
    For Each fri In fiArr
        If fri.Name.StartsWith(FileNamePrefix) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next fri


    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fri.Name)
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fri.Length)
    Response.WriteFile(fri.FullName)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

I would have expected the VB to need a `Handles` Clause, but this SO post does not have it: 
[Running a code behind routine from an <a href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548129/running-a-code-behind-routine-from-an-a-href/7548147#7548147)

The anchor tags are generated in a table so I would not know what the code as the Handles clause.

Comment: I think you can not create in client-side a server control. you need handl the event in javascript.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much what @lomed said. The `runat="server"` means the server needs to render it. Doing it all in client-side won't work.

Comment: I am new to .Net.  I think a lightbulb just went off with what the runat="server" tags does: it gets rewritten before it is sent to the client.